# Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions. React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, babeljs, preset, babel-preset-env

I'm getting this weird error and cant find a way to clear it. 
its regarding some babel preset

Please find package.json file

```
{
  "name": "wallet",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "jwt-node-decoder": "0.0.4",
    "radio-button-react-native": "^1.1.6",
    "react": "^16.6.0-alpha.8af6728",
    "react-native": "0.57.3",
    "react-native-action-button": "^2.8.5",
    "react-native-camera": "^1.1.4",
    "react-native-checkbox": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
    "react-native-device-info": "^0.21.5",
    "react-native-i18n": "^2.0.12",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.6.0",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.21.0",
    "react-native-modal-dropdown": "^0.6.2",
    "react-native-modest-checkbox": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-qrcode": "^0.2.6",
    "react-native-swipeable": "^0.6.0",
    "react-native-swipeout": "^2.3.3",
    "react-navigation": "^1.5.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.48.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.0-alpha.8af6728"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "src/app/resources/fonts/"
    ]
  }
}
```

Please let me know how to resolve this. i cant able to rectify this as it is creating lot of issue.
Please let me know how to resolve this. i cant able to rectify this as it is creating lot of issue.
Please let me know how to resolve this. i cant able to rectify this as it is creating lot of issue.

Comment: same issue, did you find any solution?

Comment: I still have this problem.

Comment: same issue here after upgrading from RN 0.56 to 0.57